# NiFi how to manage out of order when EnforceOrder is not applicable?

Tags: sorting, apache-nifi

I'm receiving real-time data that can arrive Out-Of-Order, some data arrive late compared to others. For event processing later I need to reorder the stream of flowfile and I'm trying to see if that's possible in NiFi.

My understanding of EnforceOrder is that it require an incremental integer as flowfile attribute, and knowing the starting point.

As I'm dealing with real-time flow I don't have a starting point so I don't see how to make that work.

What I have is a timestamp in the data that I can extract, convert as a linux timestamp, and write in the "priority" attribute.
So after that I setup a queue with Prioritizer = PriorityAttributePrioritizer.
But the flow file don't stay long enough in the queue to catch up the out-of-order issue, as all processor after that are fast (i'm dealing with 1200 flowfile / sec).

a) Is there a way to have a queue acting as a buffer, still keeping the speed, just delaying enough to have a fair number of flowfile in the queue to be prioritized ?

b) Or how else can we fix an out-of-order issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with 2 methods, either wait for a specific time to release a group of flow file (solution 2), or wait for a number of flow file (solution 1).
I'm using one method or the other, not both together.

In the picture here : [flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRDlF.jpg) , I've described both under solution 1 and solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had designed a waiter `process group` for this. In my case I had to wait 10 seconds to sort my flows. Below process group basically circles flows in a certain period.

You can also apply your  priority on `unmatched queue`, which should be big enough.

[image]

```
RouteOnAttribute
```

[image]

```
UpdateAttribute
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my understanding is that it will just delay, so even if there is priority sorting, the RouteOnAttribute will kick them back, one flow file that arrive at time t will pass through before one flow file that arrive at t+5 seconds
Or did I misunderstood something in the parameter ?

Comment: if your wait time is 10 seconds, t. flow and t+5. flow would be in 'unmacthed' queue in the same time so if your unmatched queue is configured to prioritize, flows are sorted and delayed.

Comment: but as unmatched is going back into the RouteOnAttribute, at t+10 : 
- the t flow will go through, 
- but the t+5 will still be back in unmatched (as it will pass only at t+15).
So whatever the sort in the unmatched the order will not be applied, the flow will just be delayed ?

Answer (score 0):

I've something here that look like working at slow speed but for the moment it breakdown at higher speed.

The first block is just a simulator that generate a flowfile par second.
The UpdateAttribute can be the one that generate the priority attribute for sorting.

The rest is to manage burst.

- Increase a counter for each flowfile
- wait for the counter to reach a limit
- if flowfiles go through, the counter is reset

[image: Solution]

The 1st Notify increment the counter by 1 for each flowfile.

[image: 1st Notify]

The Wait will let flowfile go through only if the counter reach 5
The queue before the flowfile use **PriorityAttributePrioritizer**, all the other queue will be set to FIFO.

[image: Wait]

The Last Notify that reset the counter to zero

[image: Last Notify]